# Is it possible to use 2 different examples table in Cucumber

Tags: selenium, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAPbS.png)i want to write this kind of scenario outline,and when i use the @cat1 it should run the @Cat1 table and if i use other it should run other example table. is it possible in cucumber. I'm using eclipse to run the project

@Cat1 @cat2

Scenario Outline: Test...

@Cat1

Examples:

| input |

| cat1 |

@cat2

Examples:

| input |

| cat2 |

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAPbS.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. But the tags that diffrenciate the examples should only be placed on the respective tables and not on the scenario outline.

```
Scenario Outline: Test...

@Cat1 
Examples:
|input | | cat1 |

@cat2 
Examples:
|input | | cat2 |
```

Comment: It gives me an error
"mismatched input '@Cat1' expecting 'Examples:'"

Comment: Is this an error from the IDE or after running cucumber?